# Не получается адаптивно сместить блок к низу

Tags: html, css, flexbox

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]Блок about не получается адаптивно переместить в низ экрана, как это сделать? При positipn: absolute; свойства flexbox пропадают.

```css
body, h1, h2,h3,h4, p,a {
  margin: 0;
  font-size: 100%;
  font-weight: normal;
}

@font-face {
  src: url(../fonts/AvenirNext.woff);
  font-family: "AvenirNext";
  font-weight: lighter;
}

@font-face {
  src: url(../fonts/Futura.woff2);
  font-family: "Futura";
  font-weight: bold;
}

.header {
  font-family: AvenirNext;
  list-style: none;
  text-transform: uppercase;
}

.ul {
  display: flex;
  margin:0;
  padding:0;
}

.navbar {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  align-items: center;
}

.Baikal {
  display: block;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.textheader {
  color:white;
  font-size: 25px;
  list-style: none;
  margin-right: 40px;
}


.firstpage {
  background: url(../img/baikal.webp);
  background-position: center;
  background-size: cover;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  height: 100vh;
}

.about {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-evenly;
  align-items: flex-end;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}

.about_button {
  border-radius: 25px;
  background:none;
  color: white;
  text-decoration: none;
  user-select: none;
  padding: .5em 2em;
  outline: none;
  border: 2px solid;
  transition: 0.5s;
  height: 100px;
  width: 350px;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  margin: 10px;
  padding: 15px 45px;
  font-size:30px;
  font-family: AvenirNext;
} 
.about_button:hover {
  background: rgba(255,255,255,.2);
}
  
.about_button:active { background: white; }

.about_text {
  color:white;
  font-family:Futura;
  font-size:40px;
  text-transform: uppercase;
}

.secondpage {
  height: 100vh;
  background-color:white;
}

.card {
  border-radius: 20px;
}

.card-img-top {
  border-top-right-radius:20px;
  border-top-left-radius:20px;
}

.card-img-top1 {
  height:400px;
  background: url(https://media.istockphoto.com/photos/ritual-shaman-pillars-on-olkhon-island-picture-id819559780?k=6&m=819559780&s=612x612&w=0&h=oAx_5ZeVP5OEGJy1sheuC8qMd3t-KwyyK8Q8O7V6Gdc=);
  background-size: cover;
  background-position: center;
}

.card-img-top2 {
  height:400px;
  background: url(https://media.istockphoto.com/photos/mountainous-inlet-landscape-on-a-summer-day-picture-id157770270?k=6&m=157770270&s=612x612&w=0&h=ajozuB3MpXi_WoTU_HMfQ5hSOMO-3k-zOsQ3KQfJXzE=);
  background-size: cover;
  background-position: center;
}

.card-img-top3 {
  height:400px;
  background: url(https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1614357932292-a38393b966a3?ixid=MXwxMjA3fDB8MHxwaG90by1wYWdlfHx8fGVufDB8fHw%3D&ixlib=rb-1.2.1&auto=format&fit=crop&w=675&q=80);
  background-size: cover;
  background-position: center;
}

.card-title {
  font-family: Futura;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font-size: 25px;
}

.card-text {
  font-family: AvenirNext;
}

.row {
  height: 100vh;
}

.thirdpage {
  height: 100vh;
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 1200px) {

}

@media only screen and (max-width: 1200px) {
.firstpage {
  background: url(../img/BaikalMobile.webp);
  background-size: cover;
  background-position: center;
}
.textheader {
  font-size: 20px;
  margin-right:15px;
}

.Baikal {
  display: block;
  margin-left:6px;
  margin-right: 0;
}
.about_button {
  width: 400px;
}


.about_text {
  font-size: 35px;
}
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 762px) {

}

@media only screen and (max-width: 576px) {
  .card {
    margin:40px 40px 0 40px;
  }
  }

@media only screen and (max-width: 460px) {
.textheader {
  font-size: 15px;
}
.about_text {
  font-size: 25px;}
.about_button {
  border-radius: 20px;
  height: 80px;
  width: 300px;
}
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 340px) {
  .about_button {
    height:60px;
    width: 240px;
    font-size: 20px;
  }
  
  .about_text {
    font-size:20px;
  }

  .textheader {
    font-size: 12px;
  }
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="ru">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>BaikalPage</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="assets/css/normalize.css">
    <link rel="icon" type="img" href="assets/img/Favicon.ico">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="assets/css/bootstrap-grid.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="assets/css/bootstrap-reboot.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="assets/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="assets/css/style.css">
</head>
<body>
    <div class="firstpage">
        <header class="header">
            <nav class="navbar">
                <p class="textheader Baikal">Байкал</p>
                <ul class="ul">
                    <li class="textheader"><a>Об озере</a></li>
                    <li class="textheader"><a>Вода</a></li>
                    <li class="textheader"><a>Туры</a></li>
                </ul>
            </nav>
        </header>
        <div class="about">
            <p class="about_text">Первая в мире<br> турбаза на Деревьях.</p>
                        <button class="about_button">Подробнее</button>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="secondpage">
        <div class="container">
            <div class="row align-items-center">
                <div class="card-deck">
  <div class="card">
    <div class="card-img-top card-img-top1"></div>
    <div class="card-body">
      <h5 class="card-title">Переплыть байкал</h5>
      <p class="card-text">полностью никому не удавалось. Однако, есть официальные данные о попытке:
7 августа 1988 года, Девушка из США Линн Кокс, за 4 часа и 18 минут, она смогла преодолеть расстояние в 18 километров, в холодной воде.</p>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="card">
    <div class="card-img-top card-img-top2"></div>
    <div class="card-body">
      <h5 class="card-title">Озеро Байкал</h5>
      <p class="card-text">окутано таинственными аномалиями. Во время полного штиля может появиться водяная воронка.Легенда - под этим озером располагается вход в царство умерших, а воронка является проводником.</p>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="card">
    <div class="card-img-top card-img-top3"></div>
    <div class="card-body">
      <h5 class="card-title">В озеро</h5>
      <p class="card-text">Байкал впадает около 336 рек, а берет свой исток только одна — Ангара. Если бы Ангара не вытекала из озера, то Байкал был бы морем.</p>
    </div>
    </div>
    </div>
    </div>
    </div>
</div>
    <div class="thirdpage">
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Не получается адаптивно сместить блок](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1268440/%d0%9d%d0%b5-%d0%bf%d0%be%d0%bb%d1%83%d1%87%d0%b0%d0%b5%d1%82%d1%81%d1%8f-%d0%b0%d0%b4%d0%b0%d0%bf%d1%82%d0%b8%d0%b2%d0%bd%d0%be-%d1%81%d0%bc%d0%b5%d1%81%d1%82%d0%b8%d1%82%d1%8c-%d0%b1%d0%bb%d0%be%d0%ba)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Проверьте, flex-direction. [Доки.](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/flex-direction)

**Upd (во имя развёрнутого ответа):**

Родительский элемент того, который вы хотите сместить к низу должен иметь свойство, например, `flex-direction: column;`. В таком случае `flex-end` будет помещать блок в конец, а поскольку `flex-direction: column;` то и направлены дочерние элементы будут вниз (вы же знакомы с разницей в row/column, в Bootstrap, например.

**Upd (разъясняем товарищу, ведь он предоставил ссылку на пациента, все бы так)**:
Вообще, если юзать флексы, то лучше юзать по максимуму. Вот так я заставил их работать:

```css
.firstpage {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    height: 100vh;
}
.about {
    display: flex;
    height: 100%;
    justify-content: flex-end;
    flex-direction: column;
}
```

*Отмечаю: если элементу не задать высоту, он займёт столько, сколько нужно ему. Для выравнивание посредством флексов вертикально нужно чтобы родитель был побольше с:*

Вот и все дела. Если времени изучать работу флексов нету, а использовать хочется, рекомендую посмотреть:

- [Bulma](https://bulma.io/) (Они стараются избавиться от таких вещей как jQuery для UI-слоя, но тебе никто не помешает его подключить)
- [Flex Cheatsheet](https://yoksel.github.io/flex-cheatsheet/) - тут собрали много примеров что и как.

Comment: Лучше оставлять более развернутый ответ, например, описать что делает свойство и как им пользоваться.

Comment: _Господа, если желаете удалить пост, попросите. Мне не сложно. Но тогда с вас альтернативно написанный пост, который подскажет человеку, как действовать и куда копать. Занялись тут пустой бюрократией, на вопросе всего-то с одним ответом._

Comment: При flex-direction: column; блок about не сдвигается вниз, а прижимается вправо

Comment: _Извольте ссылку на пациента, я попробую разобраться в контексте._

Comment: http://g83081.hostru08.fornex.host/maxlanding.ru/

Comment: Ловите. Должно помочь.

Comment: Сделал немножечко по другому, но вы мне очень помогли. Спасибо!